# ¿Cómo obtener el texto resaltado en PDF con JavaScript server-side?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pdf

Estoy intentando obtener los llamados highlights (o subrayados) de los PDF. Estoy utilizando PDFJS para obtener los datos del PDF del lado del servidor, hasta ahora puedo obtener las notas (o post-it) del texto subrayado, más no obtengo el texto que subrayó el usuario previamente. Este código lo escribí probando y "funciona"

```
var data = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync('./pdftests/test1.pdf'));
PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(function(stuff) {
      stuff.getTextContent().then( function(textContent){
        console.log("textContent: " + JSON.stringify(textContent));
      });
        stuff.getAnnotations().then(function(annotations){
          console.log("getAnnotations: "+ JSON.stringify(annotations));
        });

    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log('Error data');
       console.log(err);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Lo impreso por el console.log en getAnnotations es lo siguiente:

```
[ { id: '18R',
    subtype: 'Highlight',
    annotationFlags: 4,
    rect: [ 126, 617.856, 237.3855, 631.26 ],
    color: Uint8Array [ 247, 220, 0 ],
    borderStyle: 
     { width: 0,
       style: 1,
       dashArray: [Object],
       horizontalCornerRadius: 0,
       verticalCornerRadius: 0 },
    hasAppearance: true,
    annotationType: 9,
    hasPopup: true,
    title: '',
    contents: 'PRUEBA\n' },
  { id: '19R',
    subtype: 'Popup',
    annotationFlags: 0,
    rect: [ 241.3855, 617.856, 369.3855, 689.856 ],
    color: Uint8Array [ 0, 0, 0 ],
    borderStyle: 
     { width: 0,
       style: 1,
       dashArray: [Object],
       horizontalCornerRadius: 0,
       verticalCornerRadius: 0 },
    hasAppearance: false,
    annotationType: 16 } ]
```

No hallo la forma de saber cual es el texto que está resaltado.

Buscando encontré un JSFiddle que hace lo que "en sí" quiero:
http://jsfiddle.net/seikichi/RuDvz/2/

Sin embargo, al importar ese código a mi controlador, la línea 38 me da error, detallando que no hay un método fromData:

```
var annotation = PDFJS.Annotation.fromData(data);
```

La documentación de PDFJS no me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco pdfjs lo suficiente como para darte una respuesta completa, pero puedo darte buenas pistas:

- Una anotación de texto resaltado en PDF (Highlight Annotation), lo único que hace es dibujar un rectángulo en el fondo de la página antes de que se dibuje el texto, y sobre él se dibuja el contenido de la página como tal.
- Desde un objeto "Highlight Annotation" no hay como saber directamente cual es el texto que se esta resaltando, hay que usar las coordenadas del rectángulo, y con eso ir a buscar el texto en el objeto correspondiente al contenido de la página.

Esta respuesta de SO-Inglés tiene un código de ejemplo sobre como extraer el texto de una página completa, podrías usarla como base y limitar la salida a los trozos de texto que entran dentro de tu rectángulo:

[Extraer texto de un PDF desde Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript/20522307#20522307)

Detalles importantes a tener en cuenta:

- No todos los PDF permiten extraer texto legible, aunque el texto
  luzca bien en pantalla. En ocasiones, la única información que hay
  dentro del PDF es "pinta una raya desde aquí para allá, y ahora una
  curva hasta no sé donde", sin que se sepa por ningún lado que el
  resultado final es un texto.
- El texto dentro de un PDF no tiene porqué almacenarse de la misma forma que uno lo ve en pantalla, puede estar almacenado letra por letra, palabra por palabra, línea por línea, siempre por coordenadas y sin un orden específico.

Suerte